# alt-ergo does not run on windows via cygwin

Tags: frama-c, alt-ergo, why3

I am trying to run a test file on frama-c with the alt-ergo prover. However,I am getting the followng error with alt-ergo. All the other frama-c checks are fine. I know that the issue is not with the test file.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
--- Alt-Ergo (stderr) :
------------------------------------------------------------
Fatal error: exception Sys_error("/tmp/wpf0dd65.dir/typed/test_post_2_Alt-Ergo.mlw: No such file or directory")
------------------------------------------------------------
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_test_post_2 : Failed
     Error: Alt-Ergo exits with status [2]
```

I am on a windows machine and perform all of the installations via cygwin in administrator mode
I got frama-C Neon and installed it with `./configure & make & make-install`, and the installation was successful ( all the frama-c checks pass in my test file)

I got the following version of alt-ergo Linux x86_64 binary: alt-ergo-0.95.2-x86_64 from http://alt-ergo.ocamlpro.com/download.php. I went with this version, since the frama-c docs ask for version 0.95.

I used the following instructions to install alt-ergo (https://www.lri.fr/~marche/MPRI-2-36-1/install.html)

Installation of Alt-ergo

The simplest way is to get the binary file of alt-ergo. Download the file called "Linux x86_64 binary" Then:

```
   chmod +x alt-ergo-0.95.2-x86_64 
   sudo cp alt-ergo-0.95.2-x86_64 /usr/bin/alt-ergo
```

when calling `which` but frama-c and alt-ergo have a correct path

```
$ which frama-c
/usr/bin/frama-c

$ which alt-ergo
/usr/bin/alt-ergo
```

I also have why3 installed and it detects the ergo prover

```
$ why3 config --detect-provers
Found prover Alt-Ergo version 0.95.2, Ok.
1 provers detected and 0 provers detected with unsupported version
Save config to /home/username/.why3.conf
```

---

Edit

I created the following test.mlw with the online example

```
type 'a set

logic add : 'a , 'a set -> 'a set
logic mem : 'a , 'a set -> prop

axiom mem_add:
    forall x, y : 'a. forall s : 'a set.
    mem(x, add(y, s)) <->
    (x = y or mem(x, s))

logic is1, is2 : int set
logic iss : int set set

goal g:
    is1 = is2 -> 
    mem (is1, add (is2, iss))
```

running alt-ergo results in:

```
alt-ergo test.mlw
File "file.mlw", line 1, characters 1-26:Valid (0.0156) (0)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried to execute directly Alt-Ergo on /tmp/wpf0dd65.dir/typed/test_post_2_Alt-Ergo.mlw ? Or to install it from sources ?

Comment: @MohamedIguernlala I am not sure how to do that. Also /tmp/wpf... is a temporary directory that is not being created. I think the issue is that it is a windows machine, but the installation was made via cygwin (as why3,alt-ergo,frama-c required) so it has an issue with finding this path.

Comment: I downloaded alt-ergo for windows (just the .exe file) and put it in the path. trying to run ./alt-ergo.exe results in my terminal just hanging there. as for /tmp/..../ no such directory exist. Every run generates a different tmp/random_name_directory. I think the issue is windows/cygwin related. Any ideas?

Comment: If you execute Alt-Ergo without input file, it'll read data from standard input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following treats the symptoms:
using the -wp-out flag with a windows path will solve the issue

for example

```
frama-c -wp -wp-print -wp-out c:/Users/userName/Desktop/tmp2 ../../cygdrive/c/Users/userName/Desktop/swap.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the following example in a "file.mlw"

```
goal hello_world: 1+1 = 2
```

and then, try to execute your Windows and/or Cygwin binaries by providing "file.mlw" as input

Comment: So just to clarify, saving the above in a file.mlw, and running alt-ergo on file.mlw?

Comment: Yes, with /usr/bin/alt-ergo file.mlw if your Alt-Ergo binary is in /usr/bin/

Comment: Sorry for the delay (time differences). $ alt-ergo file.mlw
File "file.mlw", line 1, characters 1-26:Valid (0.0000) (0)

Comment: In addition why3 prove --prover alt-ergo file.mlw
File "file.mlw", line 1, characters 0-4:
syntax error

Comment: I think the issue is with why3 trying to write/read from tmp and having some path confusions. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Maybe you should send an email to the Why3 Discussion list